# Propositional Calculus: Stating and proving the unique readability theorem in Polish notation

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

**The Language $\mathcal{L_0}$:**
Let $\mathcal{L_0}$ be the smallest set $L$ of finite sequences of $\textit{logical symbols}= \{(\enspace)\enspace\neg\}$ and $\textit{propositional symbols}=\{A_n|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying the following properties:

(1) For each propositional symbol $A_n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
\begin{multline}
A_n \in L.
\end{multline}

(2) For each pair of finite sequences $s$ and $t$, if $s$ and $t$ belong to $L$, then
\begin{multline}
(\neg s) \in L
\end{multline} and
\begin{multline}
(s \to t) \in L.
\end{multline}

**Readability for $\mathcal{L_0}$:** Suppose that $\phi$ is a formula in $\mathcal{L_0}$. Then exactly one of the following conditions applies. 
(1) There is an $n$ such that $\phi = A_n.$
(2) There is a $\psi \in \mathcal{L_0}$ such that $\phi = (\neg\psi)$.
(3) There are $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ in $\mathcal{L_0}$ such that $\phi = (\psi_1 \to \psi_2)$

**Unique Readability for $\mathcal{L_0}$:** Same conditions as Readability, but in (2) and (3), the formulas $\psi$, $\psi_1$, and $\psi_2$ are unique, respectively.

**Problem (Polish Notation):** Let $\mathcal{P_0}$ be the smallest set of sequences $P$ such that the following conditions hold. 
a) For each $n$, $A_n \in P$. 
b) If $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ belong to $P$, then so do $\neg\psi_1$ and $\to\psi_1\psi_2 = \langle \to \rangle + \psi_1 + \psi_2$.

State and prove the unique readability theorem for $\mathcal{P_0}$

Comment: On readability, there is a typo on (2), the LHS is supposed to be $\phi$. On (1), as in another question, I don't agree with $\langle \rangle$ enclosing the propositional symbols. The set $P$ is a set of sequences of what? I must be reading something very wrong because it looks to me like $\mathcal P_0=\mathcal L_0$.

Comment: "I'm a little confused on this language. It says If $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ belong to $P$, then so do $(\neg\psi_1)$ and $(\psi_1 \to \psi_2)$. Are they at all implying that $(\neg\psi_2)$ not exist?"

Comment: It's not all implying that $(\neg \psi _2)$ doesn't exist, in fact it's saying it exists. One has $\forall \psi_1, \psi_2((\neg \psi_1)\in P\land (\psi_1\to \psi_2)\in P)$ which is equivalent to  $\forall \psi_1, \psi_2((\neg \psi_1)\in P)\land  \forall \psi_1, \psi_2((\psi_1\to \psi_2)\in P)$ which in turn implies $\forall \psi_1, \psi_2((\neg \psi_1)\in P)$ from where one gets $\forall \psi_1((\neg \psi_1)\in P)$ and finally as it is a dummy variable one gets  $\forall \psi_2((\neg \psi_2)\in P)$.

Comment: Is 'induction on the complexity of formulas' available to you yet?

Comment: Induction on length, but I'll look into induction on the complexity of formulas.

Comment: If I may ask, are you following a particular text book? If so, which?

Comment: It is an undergraduate introduction to logic textbook written by Theodore A. Slaman, professor at Berkeley (who is teaching the course), and W. Hugh Woodin.  It is called "Mathematical Logic (The Berkeley undergraduate course)" I believe it is unpublished.

Comment: Nevermind about induction on the complexity of formulas. The way $\mathcal L_0$ is defined, it's useless to mention it. Sorry.

Comment: I forgot to mention that b) can be restated as (2) and (3) on readability.

Comment: Are you still confused regarding what I tried to explain above? If you're not, I suggest we removed all of these comments which might have become useless. I am still confused about what $\mathcal P_0$ is supposed to be, it seems to me like it's just $\mathcal L_0$, but you already have unique readability for $\mathcal L_0$, so what am I missing?

Comment: I was also confused as to what it is. This is exactly how it is written in the text. I will email the professor about it. I'm assuming it is taking on the same logical and propositional symbols since it is left undefined what's in P.

Comment: Do you happen to have proved unique readability for $\mathcal L_0$ in class or in the notes? If you haven't, then I guess the problem is just that. If you did, then I'm lost too.

Comment: I have proven it for $\mathcal{L_0}$ I'm just confused really on the difference between these two.

Comment: My guess is the problem isn't supposed to be there. May I suggest we delete this useless myriad of comments?

Comment: One thing I omitted, he originally wrote it in Polish notation. It might be just an exercise in Polish notation. I think you are right that they are the same.

Comment: Ohhh, then I guess he wants you to prove it for the polish notation. I've had to do the exact same problem xD

Comment: Haha yes, my mistake. I'll rewrite and prove it in polish since I already have the proof! Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\phi$ is a formula in $\mathcal{P_0}$. Then $\phi$ is one and only one of these forms:
(1) There is an $n$ such that $\phi =A_n$.
(2) There is a $\psi$ in $\mathcal{P_0}$ such that $\phi = \neg\psi$.
(3) There are $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ in $\mathcal{P_0}$ such that $\phi = \to\psi_1\psi_2$.
Further, the $\psi_i$ in (2) and (3) are uniquely determined.

It is absolutely clear these are mutually exclusive in polish notation. All that remains is to show that in (2) and (3), these $\psi_i$ are unique:

For (2), suppose $\neg\psi_a$ = $\neg\psi_b \implies \psi_a=\psi_b \implies$ uniqueness.
For (3), suppose $\to\psi_1\psi_2=\to\psi_3\psi_4 \implies \psi_1\psi_2=\psi_3\psi_4 \implies$ one of $\psi_1,\psi_3$ is an initial segment of one another, which we know is not possible:

Let $w$ be the weight of the symbols:
$w(A_n) = 1, w(\neg)=0, w(\to) = -1$.

Then for any polish-formula $\psi = s_1\dots s_n$ of length $n$, The sum of the weights of its symbols, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}w(s_i) =1$ by induction.

Any terminal segment of a polish-formula is a concatenation of polish-formulas. So suppose $\psi'$ is a proper initial segment polish-formula of the polish-formula $\psi$, and $\psi''$ is the terminal segment of $\psi$ that makes $\psi=\psi'\psi''$.

If $\psi=\psi'\psi''$ then $w(\psi) = w(\psi')+w(\psi'')$. But $\psi''$ is a terminating segment of a polish-formula so its weight is greater than or equal to $1$. Contradiction.

Comment: "an initial segment of one another, which we know is not possible" I bet, that had to be proved as a lemma, ah?

Comment: In my text it was proved prior, but I suppose not technically in Polish notation

Comment: I included proof of the lemma