# What should be my induction hypothesis for proving the unique readability of terms in first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

The thing I want to prove is:

*If a term is one of the following then it is uniquely defined*

1. a variable
2. a constant
3. complex form, $f t_1 t_2 \cdots t_n$ where $f$ is a function of arity $n$ and $t_i$ are terms.

My attempt:

The first two cases are trivial, so I'm kinda avoiding it here.

To prove the third case, let's say the term $t$ is indeed defined in two distinct ways
$$
t :\equiv f t_1 t_2 \cdots t_n\\
t: \equiv f' t'_1 t'_2 \cdots t'_{n'}$$

the *items* $f$ and $f'$, $t_i$ and $t'_i$ are individually different from each other but when stacked they convey the same *information*. We wish to prove that $f = f'$ and $t_i = t'_i$.

Is this argument: *$f$ and $f'$ are same because if they were different then the string of symbols would start with different symbols and hence the two strings will not be equivalent*, sound?

What would be induction hypothesis for proving $t_1 = t'_1$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: work from right to left not left to right, parsing each trailing subword of the word you are working on as a sequence $t_1t_2\ldots t_m$ of terms. When you encounter a function symbol of arity $n$, if you have parsed what follows it as $t_1t_2\ldots t_m$ where $m \ge n$, then you can continue by parsing what you have as $(ft_1\ldots t_n)t_{n+1}\ldots t_m$; if $m < n$, then the word you are looking at is not a valid term. When you have worked all the way to the left, the word is a valid term if you have a sequence with just one element $t_1$. This approach to syntax is most commonly used with the symbols written from left to right: see [reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

For an inductive proof, you need to prove the stronger statement that any word $w_1\ldots w_k$ in the symbols denoting the variables, constants and functions that can be parsed while respecting the arities of the function symbols, can be parsed in at most one way as a sequence $t_1\ldots t_n$ of terms for some $n$. Then proceed by induction on $k$ taking your inductive hypothesis to be that $w_2\ldots w_k$ has this property.

Comment: I quite got you but not totally. If we have a situation like this $$ t :\equiv f t_1 \cdots t_n \\ t:\equiv f’ t’_1 \cdots t’_{n’}$$ you mean to say that we should start by saying “ $t_n = t’_{n’}$ because end symbols must be same” ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: And then? What should be my next step?

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974141/propositional-calculus-stating-and-proving-the-unique-readability-theorem-in-po (Your problem is a bit more general as you have operators of arbitrary arity, but the idea is the same.)