# Show that no prefix of a formula in Polish notation can be a formula

Tags: logic, induction

I would like to proof the mentioned statement using structural induction. It is important to note, that prefix implies that if $F = a_0 a_1 a_2 ... a_n$ then $F'$, which is a prefix of $F$ has the form $F' = a_0 a_1 ... a_m$, where $m < n$. So the number of characters in the prefix formula is strictly smaller.

The beginning of the induction is kind of straightforward. If $F = a_0$, i.e. has only one character, then $F'$ is empty which is not a propositional formula.

The reduction requirement would be that if $F$ is a propositional formula, then no prefix $F'$ is a valid propositional formula.

In the next step I proceed to show if for $F = a_0 a_1$ or $F = \lnot a_1$ then $F' = \lnot$, which is again not a propositional formula.

Now comes the part where I struggle, I do not really know how to show that it also holds for any other beginning of the formula ($\land \lor \iff \rightarrow$) or more than $2$ characters in general. Any hints?

Comment: See [Propositional Calculus: unique readability theorem in Polish notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974141/propositional-calculus-stating-and-proving-the-unique-readability-theorem-in-po)

Comment: See also [Unique Readability for Polish Notation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Unique_Readability_for_Polish_Notation)